# How to find all possible combinations of a given set of variables

Tags: r, combinations

I have a dataset with 6 variables:

```
Var1 <- c(1,0,1,0,1)
Var2 <- c(1,0,1,0,1)
Var3 <- c(1,1,1,0,1)
Var4 <- c(1,0,1,1,1)
Var5 <- c(1,0,0,0,1)
Var6 <- c(1,0,1,0,1)

DF <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6)
DF
```

which results in

```
    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
1    1    1    1    1    1    1
2    0    0    1    0    0    0
3    1    1    1    1    0    1
4    0    0    0    1    0    0
5    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I want to find all the possible variable-combinations, like how many 2 variable combinations (eg Var1Var2, Var2Var4, Var5Var4, etc...), 3 variable combinations, 4 ... etc. do I have. Is there a way to calculate this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `expand.grid()` is what you are looking for

Comment: `choose(total_number_of_variables,selected_number_of_variables)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
> choose(length(DF), 2:length(DF))
[1] 15 20 15  6  1
```

or

```
> lapply(
+   2:length(DF),
+   combn,
+   x = names(DF)
+ )
[[1]]
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10]
[1,] "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var3"
[2,] "Var2" "Var3" "Var4" "Var5" "Var6" "Var3" "Var4" "Var5" "Var6" "Var4"
     [,11]  [,12]  [,13]  [,14]  [,15]
[1,] "Var3" "Var3" "Var4" "Var4" "Var5"
[2,] "Var5" "Var6" "Var5" "Var6" "Var6"

[[2]]
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10]
[1,] "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1"
[2,] "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var3" "Var3" "Var3" "Var4" "Var4" "Var5"
[3,] "Var3" "Var4" "Var5" "Var6" "Var4" "Var5" "Var6" "Var5" "Var6" "Var6"
     [,11]  [,12]  [,13]  [,14]  [,15]  [,16]  [,17]  [,18]  [,19]  [,20]
[1,] "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var3" "Var3" "Var3" "Var4"
[2,] "Var3" "Var3" "Var3" "Var4" "Var4" "Var5" "Var4" "Var4" "Var5" "Var5"
[3,] "Var4" "Var5" "Var6" "Var5" "Var6" "Var6" "Var5" "Var6" "Var6" "Var6"

[[3]]
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10]
[1,] "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1"
[2,] "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var3" "Var3" "Var3" "Var4"
[3,] "Var3" "Var3" "Var3" "Var4" "Var4" "Var5" "Var4" "Var4" "Var5" "Var5"
[4,] "Var4" "Var5" "Var6" "Var5" "Var6" "Var6" "Var5" "Var6" "Var6" "Var6"
     [,11]  [,12]  [,13]  [,14]  [,15]
[1,] "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var3"
[2,] "Var3" "Var3" "Var3" "Var4" "Var4"
[3,] "Var4" "Var4" "Var5" "Var5" "Var5"
[4,] "Var5" "Var6" "Var6" "Var6" "Var6"

[[4]]
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var1" "Var2"
[2,] "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var2" "Var3" "Var3"
[3,] "Var3" "Var3" "Var3" "Var4" "Var4" "Var4"
[4,] "Var4" "Var4" "Var5" "Var5" "Var5" "Var5"
[5,] "Var5" "Var6" "Var6" "Var6" "Var6" "Var6"

[[5]]
     [,1]
[1,] "Var1"
[2,] "Var2"
[3,] "Var3"
[4,] "Var4"
[5,] "Var5"
[6,] "Var6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as in your case all variables are binary, the number of possible combinations given k number of variables is just: [image]

To calculate the number of combinations also for non-binary variables, you can use the function *expand.grid* and then count the number of rows. As you probably don't want to double count combinations, only count unique rows. Here is an easy example:

```
> library(dplyr)
> var1 <- c(1,2,2,3,5)
> var2 <- c(1,1,1,2,3)
> expand.grid(var1, var2) %>% unique %>% nrow
[1] 12
```